# Need to disable Grails Lazy Loading when fetching results

Tags: grails

Below are my domain classes

```
class Sender {

String senderFname;
String senderLname;
String senderPhone;

Collection receivers

static hasMany = [receivers: Receiver]
}

class Receiver {

String receiverFname;
String receiverLname;
String receiverPhone;

    static belongsTo = [sender: Sender]
}
```

I am writing logic for simple search functionality.

```
def customers() {

    println 'customers params '+params
    //def senderCriteria = Sender.createCriteria()
    def senderList = Sender.withCriteria {

        if(params.senderfname)
            like('senderFname',params.senderfname)
        if(params.senderlname)
            like('senderLname',params.senderlname)          
        if(params.senderphone)
            like('senderPhone',params.senderphone)

        createAlias("receivers", "t")

        //receivers {
            if(params.receiverfname)
                like('t.receiverFname',params.receiverfname)
            if(params.recieverlname)
                like('t.receiverLname',params.receiverlname)
            if(params.recieverphone)
                like('t.receiverPhone',params.receiverphone)
        //}


    }

    println "senderList "+senderList;

    senderList.each{ it->  println 'sender '+it
        println 'receivers '+it.receivers

    }
    //senderList = senderList.unique()
    println "senderList "+senderList;
    render(view: 'customers', model: [senderList: senderList])

}
```

There is one-to-many relationship from sender to receiver. I want to filter sender object and its corresponding receivers objects.

The main createCriteria returns expected result for sender objects. But when I access the sender object to get corresponding receivers, its loading all receivers from database again.

Is there any way to tackle this.

Comment: You want to disable the _Lazy Loading_, not the eager fetching.

Comment: @cdeszaq got that, I was confused. Now that I get it I am editing my question.

Comment: You can read about the GORM-fethcing here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#fetching you should find your answer there. I don't quite understand the question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can specify join type when you createAlias.

```
    createAlias("receivers", "t", org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
```